# How to show a degenerate critical point is a saddle point.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$f(x,y) = (x-y^2)(x-2y^2)$$

and I have found that the origin is a degenerate critical point (i.e. Hessian=0). How can I now show that the origin is actually a saddle point?